# How do I enable Clean urls within a migrated site?

Tags: 8, migrations, uri

I am currently assisting a client with a Drupal 6 to 8 upgrade. After migrating a copy of the site into a development localhost environment. I noticed that I was not able to enable clean URLs. I have checked the `.htaccess` and found the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /clientname
RewriteBase /
#Redirect /clientname

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I have have checked other forums, and according to them the issue should be fixed. However, I am dealing with this same issue.

Any new advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have `RewriteBase` twice? You should decide to only one. Can you just use `.htaccess` provided with D8? Can you make sure your `mod_rewrite` is enabled on your local?

Comment: Is "AllowOverride All" set in you Apache file?

Answer (score 0):

Did you read this:

```
  # Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
  # VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
  # For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
  # modify the following line:
  # RewriteBase /drupal
  #
  # If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,
  # uncomment the following line:
  # RewriteBase /
```

Actually, you should use the original D8 .htaccess cause there are some special rewrites for core and autoloader (and more).

Comment: Within my original question, I was referring to the .htaccess file of the Drupal 6 site that was migrated to my localhost server. I apologize for any confusion on my part.

How can I enable Clean URLs for a drupal 6 site after it has been migrated?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. If you are on a D6 site, just enable the "path" module and make sure, that you have mod_rewrite installed.